# SFTP not completing file transfer when using pexpect (python)

Tags: python, sftp, pexpect

I am currently trying to use pexpect to transfer files. It usually works fine, but recently it has been causing issues by not transferring entire files. It either truncates the file transfer or the script moves on before it is done.

My code is as follows:

```
job_id = str(job_record['control']['id'])
self.px_ssh.sendline('cd ' + self.remotePath + job_id)
self.px_ssh.prompt()
self.px_ssh.sendline('ls')
self.px_ssh.prompt()
remote_files = self.px_ssh.before.decode('utf-8')
for cop in outfiles:
  if cop in remote_files:
    print('Transferring file _from_ remote cluster:   ' + cop)
    self.px_ftp.sendline('get ' + self.remotePath + job_id + '/' + cop + ' ' + os.getcwd())
    self.px_ftp.expect('sftp>', timeout=None)
```

And the logfile:

```
get path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2/prop.in.o    path/Documents/Research/QMCDB/Runs/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2
Connected to taub.campuscluster.illinois.edu.
sftp> get path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2/prop.in.o path/Documents/Research/QMCDB/Runs/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2
Fetching path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2/prop.in.o to path/Documents/Research/QMCDB/Runs/Elemental/As/As_QMC_2x2x2/prop.in.o

path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_   0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_   0%   11MB  11.1MB/s   02:32 ETA
path/QMCDB/Elemental/As/As_   1%   22MB  11.1MB/s   02:31 ETA
```

It can be seen that it just moves on after a short time. I am not sure why it does this. Do you have any idea how to ensure the whole file is transferred before the rest of my code progresses?

Comment: I just checked the docs, and the behavior of timeout=None isn't actually defined. I'm not sure it does what you think it does.

Comment: It's on this page: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem too. I think you should wait for

```
pexpect.expect('100%')
```

possibly with a timeout. sftp seems to have asynchronous command line interface so it returns right away to the prompt while the transfer continues. Timeout is more or less relevant here since the file is truncated because the script exits while downloads are still ongoing / pending.